# Intersection of set exteriors in topology

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove on topological space​

Ext(uUv)=X-Cl(uUv)

```
           =X-(Cl(u) U Cl(v))

           =X-Cl(u) ∩ X-Cl(v)
```

Comment: What do you denote by Ext(U)?

Comment: I believe they mean the extreme points, which are typically noted as the boundary points $Bd$

Comment: Ext is the exterior of the subset.

Comment: $\operatorname{Ext}(A) = X\setminus \overline{A}$ all points that have a neighbourhood missing $A$. The exterior of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b) I agree with your derivation that

$$\operatorname{Ext}(U \cup V) =\operatorname{Ext}{U} \cap \operatorname{Ext}(V)$$ but I fail to see then how $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ is used to make the last intersection non-empty. What happens when $\operatorname{Ext}(U \cup V) =\emptyset$? Then the intersection *is* empty. An empty exterior means the set is dense. So we only need two intersecting sets whose union is dense to make a counterexample. Trivial examples include $U=V =\mathbb{Q}$ in the reals with the standard topology, but you probably come up with more.

Comment: @de.rise Yes, the example is OK.

Comment: Yes,@dr.rise  that is what I suggested. You can also use $U = [0, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $V = (-\infty, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ to make it less boring. If you take $U =V$ it just comes down to : can $\operatorname{Ext}(U)$ be empty for a non-empty set?